# Publishing Visual Studio on Azure RDS

Tags: azure

Does somebody have experience on running/publishing Visual Studio as a remote app on RDS (Azure)?

How to organize this for multiple users?

Internet does, not provide too much information about publishing an app to RDS and run it locally from remote server.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special about Visual Studio in terms of RDS, it is just another app which you can publish.

If your looking to get up to speed with RDS and RemoteApp then there are plenty of resource online for that. However, if you don't have experience with running this then I would suggest you instead look at the hosted service in Azure, [Windows Virtual Desktop](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/virtual-desktop/).

You could also look at the new [Visual Studio Online](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/visual-studio-online/) service which lets you run Visual Studio in a browser. This is currently in preview.